# MySQL data not displaying in the form of a table

Tags: android, mysql

picture

[image]Hi I have developed an app which uses the MySQL database. I have a code which retrieves the data and am trying to display the data in the form of a database.

[This](http://pastebin.com/DeKsgg1y) is my java code which accesses the database and try to print it in the form of a table dynamically.

My problem is the app force closes when I execute on a phone.

I got the following [error](http://pastebin.com/BcAqt4yi).

[This](http://pastebin.com/z8Kha88V) is my php code.

Comment: also add log when application crashing with question

Comment: when I click on the name of the store to access the database and display the data in the form of a table it gives fc as soon as I click on the name.

Comment: make sure u are getting value in `String lbl_name= myIntent.getStringExtra("lbl_name");` from prev Activity

Comment: can yo show me how to modify the code to display the data in the form of a table and also I need to add rows to the database dynamically. Please help I have a presentation today and it sort of not working and I am new to android....:(

Comment: Hi @ρяσѕρєя K are you there??

Comment: check your xml layout, is `recomain` declared as TextView or TableLayout

Comment: it is displayed as tablelayout

Answer (score 1):

Use `TableLayout` to display your data in the form of tables.Also to connect to a mySQL database, you would need to build a php script which connects to the database.You have not shown your php script,so please provide that.

Comment: php code and all is working fine I want to know how the data which is returned is displayed in the form of a table can you modify the above code so that it displays it in the form of a table.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassCastException:`
"Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass 
of which it is not an instance."

You have casted a TableLayout as TextView in your java class. So, change the TableLayout to `TextView` in your XML layout.

[Edit]
**Got it Now:**

Create a new TextView for the error to be displayed. Then change the following line:

```
 error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myErrorView);
```

[Edit 2]
Example for TableLayout (not compiled)

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/myHeading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TableLayout Example"
/>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    >

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabletv1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ID" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabletv2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabletv3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Category" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabletv4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Category" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Class

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
TextView heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myHeading);

// Your other codes

//////////////////////

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams= new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableRowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 2);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView t3 = new TextView(this);
        TextView t4 = new TextView(this);

        t1.setText(""+json_data.getInt("prod_id"));
        t2.setText(json_data.getString("prod_name"));
        t3.setText(json_data.getString("prod_category"));
        t4.setText(""+json_data.getDouble("prod_cost"));

        t1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        row.addView(t1);
        row.addView(t2);
        row.addView(t3);
        row.addView(t4);

        table.addView(row);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but I need the data to be displayed in the form of a table.

Comment: where are you setting the data in the TableLayout?? I suppose nowhere! you are just printing it out in the logout.

Comment: ok can yo modify the above code and show how to display the data?

Comment: I am getting this error   The constructor TextView(RecoProd.DownloadWebPageTask) is undefined

Comment: now I am getting this error   tablelayout1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: have you created a TableLayout with the id as `tablelayout1`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23889/discussion-between-user1929242-and-thepcwizard)